# Add columns based on another columnn existence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking for a way to find

```
 Table 1
 ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
  A        BN1
  B        BN2
  C        BN3
  D        BN4
  BN1      BN1         Min
  BN1      BN1          Max
  BN2      BN2          Mode
  BN3      BN3           Avg
  BN3      BN3            Mode
  BN5      BN5          Avg
```

I need find based on distinct values of ColumnB (when they dont match in column which means, distinct values are only of A,B,C and D in ColumnA), there exists ColumnA with any of the distinct values of ColumnB, so that I should know what are the values of ColumnC for ColumnA(which should exists based on ColumnB distinct values). For example in this BN4 doesnt exists in ColumnA , so we ignore it. BN5 exists in ColumnA but ColumnB doesnt have them (A,B,C,D) and so we ignore it.

Output should have

```
 Table 2
 ColumnD  ColumnE   ColumnF

  BN1      BN1         Min
  BN1      BN1         Max
  BN2      BN2         Mode
  BN3      BN3         Avg
  BN3      BN3         Mode
```

BN5 is ignored in this case.

Comment: Please post the code you're trying

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *
from table t
where t.columnA in ('A','B','C','D)
and t.columnB in (select distinct t1.columnB from table t1)
and t.columnC in (select distinct t2.columnC from table t2)
and t.columnD in (select distinct t3.columnD from table t3)
and t.columnE in (select distinct t4.columnE from table t4)
```